# How many megabytes per day are two nibbles per nanosecond?

Tags: sql, database, capacity-planning

One of my tables in my SQL database has a growth rate of two nibbles per nanosecond. I was wondering how many megabytes per day that is and should I be worried? My hard disk is 150 GB.

Comment: I need to ask why?  and how do you end up at such a strange figure for the growth rate?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha to the rescue!

http://www61.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=How+many+megabytes+per+day+are+two+nibbles+per+nanosecond%3F

Comment: *gasp* It says 1,000,000,000 is a gigabyte, not 953 megabytes!

Comment: +1 to WolframAlpha! Math and text interpretation on the same place, great!

Comment: Cool, never knew this existed. If only I was still in school and had to do homework..

Comment: Interestingly Google Calculator does the same thing and infers that you mean proper MiB (1048576 bytes) units! http://www.google.com/search?q=two+nibbles+per+nanosecond+in+megabytes+per+day

Answer (score 5):

Two nibbbles == one byte.
1,000,000,000 bytes per second, or 953 megabytes per second.

Let's just say your HDD can't write that fast. If it could, it would be full in under 3 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Google says: 1 nibbles per nanosecond = 476.837158 megabytes per second

In other words: Yes, very worried indeed.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=two+nibbles+per+nanosecond+in+terabytes+per+day+and+two+nibbles+per+nanosecond+in+megabytes+per+day

With this value you can imagine this huge ammount of data much better...